# Uploading Files with Angular to Symfony

Tags: angular, symfony, file-upload

I have developed a Backend in Symfony and the Frontend in Angular.
I need to be able to locate a file that is loaded into a form in the frontend.

This is part of the form, the file and submit inputs in document-new.component.html file:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="filetest">Archivo</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="filetest" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
</div>
```

The onFileSelected and onUpload methods do the following in the document-new.component.ts file:

```
onFileSelected(event) {
    //console.log(event);
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
  }

  onUpload() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('filetest', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this._http.post(this.url+'document/upload', fd)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

The path "this.url+'document/upload'" points to the upload method in the backend's DocumentController.php file

```
 public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $filetest = $request->files;

        $data = [
            'status' => 'success',
            'code' => 200,
            'message' => 'It worked!',
            'filetest' => $filetest
        ];
        
        return $this->resjson($data);
    }
```

I save the result of $ request-> files in a $ filetest variable to test if the file binary reaches the backend, and I think this is because I get a non-null or empty result:

```
"status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "message": "TEST: It worked!",
    "filetest": {
        "filetest": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8LCwkMEQ8SEhEPERETFhwXExQaFRERGCEYGh0dHx8fExciJCIeJBweHx7/2wBDAQUFBQcGBw4ICA4eFBEUHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh7/wAARCAGQAZADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHQAAAgMAAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMAAQQFBwgGCf(...)"
    }
}
```

Could someone help me to define the treatment I have to do with $request->files and be able to upload/save to the file with the backend (Symfony)?
Does anyone recommend a simpler way to do it?

Comment: In your case you get all the files which is an array of one, so you need to either loop it if you plan to upload multiple files or get it with `$file = $request->files->get("filetest")`. Something I've done in the past is define `$file` as an `UploadedFile` from the Symfony HttpFoundation. From there I simply did `$file->move($dir, $name)`. I can't say if this is the proper or even good way, but it works for me.

Comment: I will assume you already set encoding on form to "multipart/form-data", I'd create on uploader service which takes UploadedFile as an input, then simply use function move() which is present in UploadedFile and point to the location you want to save it. (use kernel.project_dir) to get absolute path to your project and then the relative path to upload file

Comment: Thanks Martin M, your comment helped me to solve or I was looking for. I just had to modify my upload method:
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $temp = $request->files;
        foreach($temp as $f) {
            $name = date("YmdHis") . '.' . $f->guessExtension();
            $f->move('uploadTest/', $name);
        }
$data = [
            'status' => 'success',
            'code' => 200
        ];
        return $this->resjson($data);
    }